# Change height Navigation Tab ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android

I use NavigationTab of ActionbarSherlock, i search on google to change height tab, but i can't do it.

[image]

```
<style name="customActionBarTabStyle" parent="style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item  name="android:height">35dp</item>
</style>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: does it work on devices with android 3.2+?

Comment: yes, it also work on android 2.3.3.

Comment: I mean the android:height properties. Does it work only on device wit Android 3.2+

Comment: i test on android 4.2.2 but it doesn't work.

Comment: <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Changing `actionBarSize` will change both the tabs height and the main action bar height**

In the main theme of you app, add the following property:

```
<item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/my_actionbar_size</item>
```

You should also add a duplicate theme in `values/v-11` that additionally has the property:

```
<item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/my_actionbar_size</item>
```

And then in your dimens, you can declare

```
<dimen name="my_actionbar_size">48dp</dimen>
```

Comment: the opening bracket starts with <item> but the closing is </dimen> ? I believe it would be incorrect.